# Access xbox music api

Tags: api, windows-phone-8, xbox

Is there any API access to the new XBOX music store? I heard there was a small and simple one for the zune store I would like to access a database of song: titles, artists, genres, and previews for windows 8 phone development dealing with music and purchasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of the Xbox data is based on JSON or OData feeds. There are no official SDK/APIs to obtain this type of information, however you could easily find the feeds you require by using Fiddler and intercepting the requests from Xbox music on your device and subscribing to the same data. There is a guide to using Fiddler on Windows Phone here: www.fiddler2.com/phone/

There is obviously a significant risk of the feed changing, and impacting your app - so if you are going to do something like this I would advise proxying the data through your own service so you can rapidly make and deploy changes if something breaks.

Answer (score 3):

There is one. It's RESTful and provides features like:

- Get the details of an album, an artist, or a track if you know its
  ID.
- Search for any album, artist, or track details based on a string
  of keywords—for example, "Madonna hang up".
- Get the top tracks and newest albums of an artist.
- Get a deep link that redirects nicely to the Xbox Music applications
  on any platform.
- Get album covers.
- Get artist images.

All the details [here](http://music.xbox.com/developer).

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here at SO.  Try adding the points of the link to your post in case the link goes bad in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not directly answer your question, there is a built-in API to let you *search* for content in the Xbox Music store.

```
MarketplaceSearchTask task = new MarketplaceSearchTask();
task.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Music;
task.SearchTerms = term;
task.Show();
```